# vs 2017 - python intellisense not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

As the title suggests I am using Visual Studio 2017 to work with a python project and the intellisense is not working.

[image]

I tried refreshing the intellisense db, but its is stuck at the dateutil package

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a sample to show the intellisense not working? I will tried to test it in my side, meanwhile, you can try to restart vs, create a new python or repair VS, reinstall the python development workload to have a try if all python projects have this issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same intellisense-issue (stuck on dateutil)  with 15.9 ... Hugues Valois [MSFT] · 12 09 2018 um 21:56 0
...we are no longer working on the old database driven IntelliSense, and it has already been removed from the next major release (dev16) ..

Comment: They started in 16.x with the new ai-based intellicode, which seems not to be database oriented.https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/07/30/python-intellicode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, this is the new ai enabled intellicode plugin for VS 2017 (python). You can install it and test the result.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode
[image]
Turn intellisense database !OFF! by setting -> tools->options->python->experimental->!ON!

Now it works with the new ai-based intellicode.
[image]

There may be a short delay-time, which is ai-backend-communication-referred (https://prod.intellicode.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/). But after a short time you get all intellicode informations - may be - perhaps it may last one day :) ). Repeat the dot several times if necessary.

Best
Axel Arnold Bangert - Herzogenrath 01.2019